# Accessing SonarQube quality gate API for private projects

Tags: api, sonarqube, access-token

How do I access SonarQube quality gate API in case of a private project? I tried sending the "User token" for a user as `Authorization` Bearer token  and Basic login. However, it did not work. The only way I can access it is from a browser when a user is logged in, i.e. login token is present. Accessing like that from Postman is also possible. How could I get the token, then and is that a right way to access the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are indeed the right way to access the API.

1) You can obtain a new token by going to 
Administration > Security > Users under tokens (click the list icon) then enter a name and click Generate

Make sure to copy the token as you won't be able to see it once you close.

2) Postman has an option to generate code based on a request (click the "code" option). If it works through Postman, it should work in your code with the copied request.

3) As a last resort if it doesn't work, here is a Groovy function I wrote to send a Get request.

```
// Returns response of SonarQube web API call with admin auth in text format
def getFromApi(String getURL){

    def Res = ("curl -u "+AuthenticationToken+": "+getURL).execute().text

    if (Res){
        return Res
    }

    else{ 
        return "error"
    }
}
```

For post request you just need to add -X POST before the authentication token. Modify it to suit your needs. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, however I used Powershell's `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet (unfortunately, the SQ server is on a Windows server). I couldn't login with curl -u token, but I was able to login with curl -u user:password. It worked on Ubuntu, however, on Windows I had to create credentials objects etc. I am not entirely sure what I had done, but it works now. I would still prefer sending `curl -u` - like request in groovy.